# SQL Help - Think I need a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have wrote the following query.

```
SELECT pro.[Id], COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM {Task} tsk
JOIN {profile} pro ON tsk.[ProfileId]=pro.[Id]
GROUP BY 
    pro.[Id]
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

This returns the records I am interested in but it returns the following...

```
ID       Count
12345    3
21254    2
25458    2
```

I now need to take it a stage further and I think I would need to use the query I have wrote within another query to get what I need.

I basically need to see the underlying data in the count e.g. task-number.  So the end result will look something like this based on the above example.

```
ID       Count
12345    123-345
12345    135-564 
12345    136-985
21254    124-856
21254    135-854
25458    214-854
25458    365-850
```

Am I correct in thinking I need a subquery to do this and how would I go about it?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of database is this? mysql, mssql etc..?

Comment: It's SQL Server but it's in a low code environment hence all the weird brackets which can be ignored.

Comment: Is it Microsoft SQL Server, or what do you mean? Server SQL is not something I've heard about.

Comment: Sorry, yes Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data from what {Task} and {profile} contains? If done in an SQL Fiddle, people will be able to help you quicker.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about SQL fiddle, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go with a CTE, count, filter then join

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT pro.[Id], COUNT(*) AS Count 
FROM {Task} tsk
JOIN {profile} pro ON tsk.[ProfileId]=pro.[Id]
GROUP BY 
    pro.[Id]
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT tsk.[Id], tsk.[ProfileId] FROM CTE
JOIN {Task} tsk ON CTE.[Id] = tsk.[ProfileId]
```

Comment: Or even use an EXISTS instead of JOIN. Let me know if you need help and I can write it up.

Comment: Thanks, just tried this and got this error The multi-part identifier "tsk.Id" could not be bound

Comment: To write up 100% correctly I need the format of the underlying tables and data. But the question should suffice with respect to the logic necessary.

Comment: We posted at the same time I think. Thanks for your help I appreciate it. I tried with the answer you provided and got the above error message.

Comment: Syntax error -> Incorrect syntax near 'pro'.

Comment: Edited it. You got some sample data somewhere I could use?

Comment: Wow, I think this may have worked. I needed to add tsk.[Id] into the bottom select statement but it has returned some results and the volume also seems reasonable. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, it's almost worked, I probably needed profile ID in that select as both columns are now showing the tsk ID.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks tsk.[profileId]

Comment: Try also using EXISTS instead of the second JOIN. It should be faster.